# smbclient fails silently to copy file in bash script

Tags: bash

I have the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh
BACKUP=/respaldoBD
NOW=$(date +"%d_%m_%Y")
SMBCLIENT="$(which smbclient)"
DBS="zabbix"
for db in $DBS
do
  FILE="mysql_$db.$NOW.gz"
  echo $FILE
  PARM="prompt; recurse; mput $FILE; exit;"
  for f in $FILE
  do
    $SMBCLIENT //192.168.3.57/publica -A $BACKUP/.smbclient -c "\""$PARM"\$
  done
done
```

When i execute the script, i only get "Domain=[SEGCAT] OS=[Windows 8.1 Pro 9600] Server=[Windows 8.1 Pro 6.3]" and the file doesn't get copied.

If i echo the $smbclient line, and copy and paste it directly, it copies the file perfectly. I don't know what's happening, it doesn't make sense to me.

EDIT: the fix was to replace the $SMBCLIENT line with:
    $SMBCLIENT //192.168.3.57/publica -A $BACKUP/.smbclient -c "prompt; recurse; mput $FILE; exit;"